# How Merge transaction qty from one dataframe into another dataframe based on date conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I've been searching for days and have not been able to get an answer to work for my situation.

I have two data frames: skus:

```
skus <- data.frame("SKU_ID"= c(123,234,345,135,135,234),
                   "date1"=c(as.Date("2020-01-10"),as.Date("2020-01-05"),as.Date("2020-01-11"),as.Date("2020-01-10"),
                    as.Date("2020-01-15"),as.Date("2020-01-15")),
                      "date2"=c(as.Date("2020-01-20"),as.Date("2020-01-08"),as.Date("2020-01-15"),as.Date("2020-01-12"),
                                as.Date("2020-01-20"),as.Date("2020-01-25")))
```

and: transactions:

```
transactions <- data.frame("SKU_ID"=c(123,123,123,234,234,234,234,234,345,345,135,135,135,135),
                           "date"=c(as.Date("2020-01-02"),as.Date("2020-01-11"),as.Date("2020-01-17"),as.Date("2020-01-05"),
                                     as.Date("2020-01-07"),as.Date("2020-01-09"),as.Date("2020-01-16"),as.Date("2020-01-17"),
                                     as.Date("2020-01-12"),as.Date("2020-01-12"),as.Date("2020-01-11"),as.Date("2020-01-12"),as.Date("2020-01-18"),
                                     as.Date("2020-01-20")),
                           "qty"=c(2,3,6,1,9,2,9,34,1,23,12,18,21,62))
```

I am attempting to get the following output:

```
desiredOutput <- data.frame("SKU_ID"= c(123,234,345,135,135,234),
                   "date1"=c(as.Date("2020-01-10"),as.Date("2020-01-05"),as.Date("2020-01-11"),as.Date("2020-01-10"),
                             as.Date("2020-01-15"),as.Date("2020-01-15")),
                   "date2"=c(as.Date("2020-01-20"),as.Date("2020-01-08"),as.Date("2020-01-15"),as.Date("2020-01-12"),
                             as.Date("2020-01-20"),as.Date("2020-01-25")),
                   "qty"=c(9,10,24,30,83,43))
```

I have tried sqldf, dplyr and data.table solutions but nothing quite gives me the results I am looking for.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a dplyr solution.

```
skus %>% 
  inner_join(transactions, by=c("SKU_ID"), suffix = c(".a", ".b")) %>% 
  filter(date1 <= date & date2 >= date) %>% 
  group_by(SKU_ID, date1, date2) %>% 
  summarise(qty = sum(qty)) %>% 
  ungroup() 

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  SKU_ID date1      date2        qty
   <dbl> <date>     <date>     <dbl>
1    123 2020-01-10 2020-01-20     9
2    135 2020-01-10 2020-01-12    30
3    135 2020-01-15 2020-01-20    83
4    234 2020-01-05 2020-01-08    10
5    234 2020-01-15 2020-01-25    43
6    345 2020-01-11 2020-01-15    24
```

Answer (score 1):

Or in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(skus)[, qty := 
    setDT(transactions)[.SD, on=.(SKU_ID, date>=date1, date<=date2), 
        by=.EACHI, sum(qty)]$V1
]
```